# Expected value of a random closed curve given its length

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Exactly what the title says :) What is the expected value of the area of a random closed curve of known constant length?

Is there any hope that the question itself is valid, and if so, any hope of a solution?

Clearly the maximum (say, for length $2\pi$) is achieved when the curve is a circle, and is obviously $\pi$.

Equally clearly, the minimum is zero as you can make a closed curve of zero area.

But suppose we have a random, suppose even non-self-intersecting, closed curve -- can we even imagine such a thing as its expected area?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do so without formulating how the random curve is chosen.

Comment: What do  you mean by 'area of a curve'?

Comment: I’d guess that he or she means the area of the region enclosed by the curve.

Comment: @bubba of course that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: @user6247850 I mean random curve among all possible curves that have the total length of exactly $L$

Comment: But you need to specify some sort of distribution over those curves.  Like you can't say anything meaningful about selecting "a random number."  You would need to say a random number from a Gaussian distribution, or from a $U(0,1)$ distribution, etc.

Comment: ...But not "a number uniformly random on $(0..+\infty)$. Well, can we have the equivalence of the two questions proven? I too have the feeling that it is the case, but in maths, we don't exactly like feeling, preferring the proofs instead :)